# Why SQL Server doesn't treat this code erratic?

Tags: sql-server

It not actually a problem that i'm facing. But i'm just wondering that the first 
line in the code written below should be treated as a syntax error by SQL Server because of the extra comma (,) in the end of columns list. But it runs the code fine. Does anyone know the reason?

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(COL1 INT,COL2 VARCHAR,)    
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES (1,'A')    
SELECT * FROM #TEMP    
DROP TABLE #TEMP
```